# multiprocessing script to scan for new values and put in queue not working

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Here is my script:

```
# globals
MAX_PROCESSES = 50
my_queue = Manager().Queue() # queue to store our values
stop_event = Event() # flag which signals processes to stop
my_pool = None

def my_function(var):
   while not stop_event.is_set():
        #this script will run forever for each variable found
        return


def var_scanner():
    # Since `t` could have unlimited size we'll put all `t` value in queue 
    while not stop_event.is_set(): # forever scan `values` for new items
        x = Variable.objects.order_by('var').values('var__var')
        for t in x:
            t = t.values()
            my_queue.put(t)
        time.sleep(10) 

try:
    var_scanner = Process(target=var_scanner)
    var_scanner.start()
    my_pool = Pool(MAX_PROCESSES)

    while not stop_event.is_set():
        try: #  if queue isn't empty, get value from queue and create new process
             var = my_queue.get_nowait() # getting value from queue 
             p = Process(target=my_function, args=("process-%s" % var))
             p.start()
        except Queue.Empty:
             print "No more items in queue"

except KeyboardInterrupt as stop_test_exception:
     print(" CTRL+C pressed. Stopping test....")
     stop_event.set()
```

However I don't think this script is exactly what I want. Here's what I was looking for when I wrote the script. I want it to scan for variables in "Variables" table, add "new" variables if they don't already exists to the queue, run "my_function" for each variable in the queue.

I believe I have WAYYYY to many while not stop_event.is_set() functions. Because right now it just prints out "No more items in queue" about a million times.

Please HELP!! :)

Comment: when using multiprocessing, you can not share data that easily. You have to use queues like rabbitmq/zeromq to pass information between process. In case of simple data structures, pickling would work too. All your processes get different copies of my_queue, stop_event etc.

Comment: If your are not really sure why you need multiprocessing but want to share data easily, then go for eventlet.

Comment: @Akilesh I'm pretty damn sure I need multiprocessing if I want to run an infinite function for each variable found. I mean, I guess I could just run the function for each and then loop back around. But as the code is written right now, it runs and then goes idle for each variable. Suggestions?

Comment: if the processing for each variable is intense stick with multiprocessing and check on how to share data using external applications like zeromq or rabbitmq or redis server or memcached. It is a rather long story. If your processing thread is going to be idle most of the time then use coroutines like eventlet/gevent instead of multiprocessing. Most of the time what people need in coroutines instead of parallel processing.